# Таблица html не раздвигается?

Tags: php, html, css

У меня такая проблема! Есть html таблица и в одной из ее ячеек циклом через printf выводится иноформация! но ошибка в том что иноформация не раздвигает таблицу в низ как должно быть а вылазиет прямо поверх страницы!! код выглядит примерно так:

```
<table>
<td>
<tr>
<?php
$tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM    messages WHERE poluchatel='$myrow[login]' ORDER BY id DESC",$db); 
            $messages =    mysql_fetch_array($tmp);
if (!empty($messages['id'])) {
            do 
              {
            $author = $messages['author'];
            $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT avatar,id    FROM users WHERE login='$author'",$db); //извлекаем аватар 
            $myrow4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4);

if (!empty($myrow4['avatar']))    {
            $avatar = $myrow4['avatar'];
            }
            else {$avatar =    "avatars/net-avatara.jpg";}
     printf("
                 <table>
                 <tr>
                 <td><a href='page.php?id=%s'><img alt='аватар'    src='%s'></a></td>
                 <td>Автор:    <a href='page.php?id=%s'>%s</a><br>
                  Дата:    %s<br>
                                 Сообщение:<br>

                             %s<br>

                 </td>  
                 </tr>
                 </table><br>
                 ",$myrow4['id'],$avatar,$myrow4['id'],$author,$messages['date'],$messages['text'],$messages['id']);
              //выводим само сообщение 
              }
                 while($messages = mysql_fetch_array($tmp));
                    }

?>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

(К сожалению коряво получилось напечатать( но работает все правильно но сообщения вылазят не раздивигая таблицу - мне кажется что функция printf почему то печатает все поверх документа ОО

Comment: Тут бы на стили страницы взглянуть. Причем здесь РНР?

Comment: Вторую строку поменяйте с третьей. `<td><tr>` - должно быть `<tr><td>`

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. не юзай в таких случаях do while. если вернется пустой массив, скрипт будет делать лишнюю работу
2. не юзай printf. юзай echo. не грузи скрипт

Comment: ммм а эхо тоже ожет как printf - вставлять переменные через %s ??

Comment: в смылсе так надо?
echo"
                 <table>
                 <tr>

                 <td><a href='page.php?id=$myrow4[id]'><img alt='аватар'    src='$avatar'></a></td>
              
                 <td>Автор:    <a href='page.php?id=$myrow4[id]'>$author</a><br>
                  Дата:    $messages['date']<br>
                                 Сообщение:<br>

                             $messages['text']<br>
                             
              
                 </td>  
                 </tr>
                 </table><br>";

Comment: @DanteLoL, нет, вот так http://pastebin.com/XiUSriFc

Comment: все равно не раздвигает(

Comment: сделайте пример таблицы на jsfiddle со стилями и контентом. Будем разбираться на живом примере.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GpG9R/ вот пожалуйста - в полный код страницы - в данном примере я попробовал вывести через while - альтернативный синтаксис но эфект тот же( 582 - строка - это начало цикла ..

Comment: Там где должен быть HTML вставьте результат работы скрипта. Скопируйте туда Source code страницы, который внутри тэгов <body>

Answer (score 0):

Поковырялся я ради забавы. Обнаружил, что во второй ячейке (<!-- 2я ячейка -->) DIV открывается, но не закрывается. Он то и может быть проблемой. Хотя в той каше я мог что-то упустить. Я позволю себе несколько замечаний по коду.

1. Начну с того, что с таким кодом работать нельзя! Нет можно конечно, но это же головная боль неимоверная. Ошибку найти - это как иголку в стоге сена искать.
2. Я рекомендую (ОЧЕНЬ) снова почитать об HTML. Разные тэги придуманы не для красоты, а для чего-то предназначены. Если браузер это пережевывает, это не значит что он правильный. И думайте о людях с ограниченными возможностями! Для них правильный HTML - это важно!!! Ну и для поисковиков это будет полезно.

<span> - это строчный элемент, а не блочный и не нужно туда помещать <form> и полстраницы в придачу
<form> - это блочный элемент и он может существовать самостоятельно на странице без обертки. Внутри тэга <form> желательно использовать такие тэги как <label>, <fieldset> и др.
<p> - это параграф. Он используется с текстом в основном и в форме ему не место.

1. Не используйте (или сводите к минимуму) стили внутри тэгов.
2. Если вынести отдельные части РНР в отдельные функции - код станет почище и более удобным для поддержания.

Comment: спасибо учту) но все оказалось проще просто Span который был у формы не был закрыт)